# how to get user info in anonymous user can visit page in spring security

Tags: spring-security

A public page ,such as the first page of a website,all the user can visit,contains anonymous user.
so i config it in applicationContext-security.xml like this:

```
 <intercept-url pattern="/index" access="permitAll" />
 <intercept-url pattern="/css/**" access="permitAll" />
 <intercept-url pattern="/javascript/**" access="permitAll" /> 
 <intercept-url pattern="/**"
        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_MANAGER','ROLE_ORGANIZATION')" />
```

I want to get user info if a use signin.I use the code below:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .getAuthentication().getPrincipal()
```

Then i get null even if i have signin.

I think is config error. Anyone know why or where ?  thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your code.Normally in a case of anonymous user your principal will be a simple string "anonymousUser". I think the main problem is that **AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(...)** was not called. **AnonymousAuthenticationFilter** is responsible for injecting of anonymous authentication into SecurityContextHolder. Make sure that HTTP request related to

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()
```

call is covered by Spring Security filter chain. Make a brakepoint in **AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter()**. If it is not called then check your web.xml. Be sure that your filter chain is applied to all HTTP calls:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: thanks。i get a string anonymousUser instead of user info after i signin.That's the problem.How can i get user info in these page?

Comment: You must be logged in. Then you will get **org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User** instance instead of string "anonymousUser."